# Evaluate $3\tan30^\circ$, leaving answer rational denominator

Tags: trigonometry

I keep getting $3$, instead of $\sqrt 3$. Can someone show me solution to this basic problem please? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

$$3 \tan{\pi/6} = 3 \frac{\sin{\pi/6}}{\cos{\pi/6}} = 3 \frac{1/2}{\sqrt{3}/2} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}} =\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{3} = \sqrt{3}. $$

In general (suggested by your previous questions):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a} \times \sqrt{a} } = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{a}, \quad a > 0.$$ This is often called *rationalizing*.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\tan(30^\circ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$3=\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan 30^\circ=\large \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

So,$$3\tan30^\circ=\large \frac{3}{\sqrt3}=\frac{3}{\sqrt3}\times\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}=\sqrt3$$